# Operator <= not compatible with types struct Counters.Counter. solidity / open zeplin

Tags: blockchain, solidity

im very new to solidity and im working on a project that requires a minting function. im using open zeplin and i was trying to set a minting limit - `require(_tokenIds <= stock);`. when i try it throws an err saying `Operator <= not compatible with types struct Counters.Counter`. from what i realized i cant use `<=` when using open zeplin counter function. is there a soulution? here's the full code:

````
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";


contract EtherumLottery is ERC721URIStorage{

    // keep track of the tokens 
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721 ("EtherumTicketStand", "ECON") {
        console.log("Etherum conference");
    }


    // mint a ticket
    function mint() public payable{
        
        // get the current token id
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();

        // stock variable 
        uint256 stock; //still needs to be set

        //as long as the product is not out of stock
        require(_tokenIds <= stock);

        // mint and send to the new owner 
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        
        // set the jason metadata on chain 
        // jason meta data base64 encoded variable
        string memory Base64Jason = "data:application/json;base64,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";
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, Base64Jason);

        // printing a msg to let the user know
        console.log("An ticket w/ ID %s has been minted to %s", newItemId, msg.sender);

        console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------");

        console.log("you can see your jason meta data here ", Base64Jason);

        // increment the token id so there wont be 2 the same
        _tokenIds.increment(); 
        
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Counters` smart contract use a struct called Counter. Inside it, there is a single variable with uint datatype that counting your tokens.
In details, your issue refers that you're using '<=' operator between struct and uint. You must change this expression:

```
require(_tokenIds <= stock);
```

in this way:

```
require(_tokenIds._value <= stock);
```

I adjusted your original smart contract. You can see below this line:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract EtherumLottery is ERC721URIStorage {

    // keep track of the tokens 
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721 ("EtherumTicketStand", "ECON") {
        console.log("Etherum conference");
    }

    // mint a ticket
    function mint() public payable {
        
        // get the current token id
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();

        // stock variable 
        uint256 stock; //still needs to be set

        //as long as the product is not out of stock
        require(_tokenIds._value <= stock);

        // mint and send to the new owner 
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        
        // set the jason metadata on chain 
        // jason meta data base64 encoded variable
        string memory Base64Jason = "data:application/json;base64,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";
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, Base64Jason);

        // printing a msg to let the user know
        console.log("An ticket w/ ID %s has been minted to %s", newItemId, msg.sender);

        console.log("---------------------------------------------------------------");

        console.log("you can see your jason meta data here ", Base64Jason);

        // increment the token id so there wont be 2 the same
        _tokenIds.increment(); 
        
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked so thank you Kerry99 but i noticed you changed my Base64Jason to a var set to "test.com" can you explain to me why and how do i access test.com? thanks a lot ```string memory Base64Jason = "test.com";```

Comment: Oh no, I changed it for debug on my computer. I updated that line like your original smart contract